# Angular2 setTimeout returning ZoneTask rather than a "Number"

Tags: javascript, angular, settimeout

Trying to use setTimeout in angular2 and I want to clear the timeout later.

But Angular2 is returning a "ZoneTask" rather than a number

```
constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {  
      console.log('hello');
    }, 2000);


    console.log("timeout ID---", this.timeoutId); // Output - ZoneTask {_zone: Zone, runCount: 0, _zoneDelegates: Array[1], _state: "scheduled", type: "macroTask"…}_state: "notScheduled"_zone: Zone_zoneDelegates: nullcallback: function () {cancelFn: nulldata: Objectinvoke: function () {runCount: 0scheduleFn: function scheduleTask(task) {source: "setTimeout"state: (...)type: "macroTask"zone: (...)__proto__: ZoneTask app.ts:24

  }
```

How do I use the normal setTimeout or what is the preferred to use  setTimeout and then clearTimeout in Angular2?

[Plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/DBMDpx62VrsClKdqPvmq?p=preview)

Comment: Try `clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);` without first argument or you can get id  by using `this.timeoutId.data.handleId`

Comment: yes but why am I getting a ZoneTask? How do I do a normal settimeout!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

Relase [zone@0.8.18 (2017-09-27)](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0818-2017-09-27)

> timer: fix #314, setTimeout/interval should return original timerId
>   (#894) (aec4bd4)

Previous version

You need to call

```
clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
```

The `timeoutId` you can get by calling

```
this.timeoutId.data.handleId
```

If you wish to use native `setTimeout` then you can leverage something like this:

```
this.timeoutId = window['__zone_symbol__setTimeout'](() => {  
  console.log('hello');
}, 2000); // setTimeout will work, but it returns ZoneTask

console.log("timeout ID---", this.timeoutId);
window['__zone_symbol__clearTimeout'](this.timeoutId); // clearTimeout will also work
```

But i don't understand why you wish that

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Basically you are saying I need not worry about the ZoneTask and just use clearTimeout like we do normally in javascript?

Comment: Yes, you should not worry about this